# Unable to run Leak Instruments in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I am using xcode 4 and tried to run the leaks tool by clicking on the Product > Profile button in the top menu.

I checked that I am using the development provisioning profile when running the tool (no issues with running the app in 'run' mode'.

However, I got the following error. Any advise on how I can overcome this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by running normally via Xcode to install the app but then quitting and relaunching the app directly from Instruments.